JAXB mapping element to field based on element attribute value
Given this XML:
<child>
   <entry key="foo-id">abc</entry>
   <entry key="bar-id">xyz</entry>
   <entry key="baz-id">mno</entry>
</child>

how can I use JAXB to map it to a class like this:
class Child {
    String fooId; // with value abc
    String barId; // with value xyz
    String bazId; // with value mno
}

